# Jobject using .Add in a nested element

Tags: c#, json

If I had a Json Object:

```
{ 
"data":{
      "SomeArray":[
         {
            "name":"test1"
         },
         {
            "name":"test2"
         },
         {
            "name":"test3"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

And this object is Parsed using `Jobject.Parse(jsonString);`

How would I add a field under `data` that holds the count of the items in the array to be forwarded tro another system. The count has already been calculated. I just need to add it in like this:

```
{ 
"data":{
      "Count" : 3,
      "SomeArray" : [
```

I have tried

```
myJObject["data"].Add("Count",count);
```

But .Add does not work here. The only option I see is `AddAfterSelf()`

Is there no way to just add a simple key value pair without having to create  `Jproperty` first and add it using `AddAfterSelf`?

Or is the correct way: `x["Data"].AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("Count", count));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `myJObject["data"]` returns an `JToken` which is base class for JObject.

If you're sure that "data" will be always an object, you can do following

```
var data = myJObject.GetValue("data") as JObject;
data.Add("Count",120);
```

Comment: How would I then add the data back into the original JObject, just by doing `myJObject["data"] = data; ` ?

Comment: @Bike_dotnet you should not do it. it will be automatically present in `myJObject` because it is referenced data type.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by casting the `JToken` that you get from `myJObject["data"]` as a `JObject`. For example:

```
var data = (JObject)myJObject["data"];
data.Add("Count", 3);
```